# Search keyword in document in python

Tags: python, keyword

I am trying to write a python script so that it can search for a keyword in a document, and retrieve the entire sentence where the keyword is. From my research i saw that acora can be used but i still found it unsuccessful.

Comment: `$ cat document.txt | grep "keyword"`

Comment: @Franklin that's completely different from what he said. He asks for sentence.

Comment: yes, i realise that the grep "keyword" is just for the "keyword". But what i am looking for is, if the keyword appears, i am trying to grab the entire sentence where the keyword is. any ideas?

Comment: A general note that I think will apply to most or all of the answers: it is not trivial to determine when a sentence ends. A period can be part of an abbreviation - for example, ``I am being treated by Dr. House.`` is one sentence not two. Question and exclamation marks in parentheses (is this an example?) do not end the main sentence, just the sub-sentence. And with a quotation - he said, "I like olives." - the closing quotation mark comes after the period.

Comment: In your situation - and many others - this may not be an issue if the occasional errors arising from it can be accepted. But it is worth being aware of in the general case.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> text = """Hello, this is the first sentence. This is the second. 
And this may or may not be the third. Am I right? No? lol..."""

>>> import re
>>> s = re.split(r'[.?!:]+', text)
>>> def search(word, sentences):
       return [i for i in sentences if re.search(r'\b%s\b' % word, i)]

>>> search('is', s)
['Hello, this is the first sentence', ' This is the second']
```

Comment: -1: Your function matched the third sentence even though it doesn't contain the word ``is``. It contains the *sequence* ``is`` in the word ``this``.

Comment: @Blair oh yeah. Didn't realized that. It's pretty simple to fix and you also should downvote every other answer as they also used `word in sentence` to find.

Comment: @Blair can't believe you really did that. Try being nice bro

Comment: @Blair, a bit harsh but fair enough, well spotted. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Now its fixed I've changed the downvote to an upvote. In hindsight it might have been a bit harsh, but in all fairness the example output you provided was blatantly wrong...

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can simply do it in shell. You should write it in script yourself.

```
>>> text = '''this is sentence 1. and that is sentence
              2. and sometimes sentences are good.
              when that's sentence 4, there's a good reason. and that's 
              sentence 5.'''
>>> for line in text.split('.'):
...     if 'and' in line:
...         print line
... 
 and that is sentence 2
 and sometimes sentences are good
 and that's sentence 5
```

Here I splitted `text` with `.split('.')` and iterated, then controlled with word `and` and if it contains, printed it.

You should also consider that this is **case-sensitive**. You should consider many things on your solution, such as things ending with `!` and `?` are also sentences (but sometimes they aren't)

> This is a sentence (ha?) or do you think (!) so?

is going to be splitted as

- This is a sentence (ha
- ) or do you think (
- ) so

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with this but you might be looking for [`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/).

Try [this](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer-class.html); use `span_tokenize` and find which span the index of your word falls under, then look that sentence up.

Answer (score 0):

use grep or egrep commands with subprocess module of python, it may help you.

e.g:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

stdout = Popen("grep 'word1' document.txt", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout
#to search 2 different words: stdout = Popen("egrep 'word1|word2' document.txt",       
#shell=True, #stdout=PIPE).stdout
data = stdout.read()
data.split('\n')
```